# как позиционировать div без position

Tags: html, css

Подскажите основные инструменты позиционирования блоков div БЕЗ свойства position. Верстаю html-письмо а там position не жалуют. Боюсь, что вся верстка поедет.

Comment: Таблички наше всё

Comment: html письма верстают только на таблицах и больше ни как , css только inline способом

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Воспользуйтесь фреймворком для верстки писем https://mjml.io/.

Comment: Спасибо. Так горело, что за ночь разобрался с zurb fundation. Просто супер штука.